# Microcontroller and Bluetooth application

Tags: microcontroller

I have to design a pedometer, (theoretically, just to suggest the components with a description) so the device needs to detect any movements using an accelerometer. It will then be connected to a microcontroller in order to display the values on a LCD panel. The device should also be capable of communicating with blue-tooth devices.

1. Can I use a 8-bit or 10-bit digital accelerometer with a 16-bit microcontroller?
2. Instead of using a ready bluetooth device which is expensive, can I use an antenna (2.4GHz where bluetooth devices operate too) and then connect it to the microcontroller to manage communication with other bluetooth devices? A brief description of how this is possible would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, that is the usual solution. You could use an 8-bit MCU.

2) No, you need a Bluetooth module interfaced to the MCU.

Comment: thanx for your answer. its ok, done it

Comment: Use any device you are familiar with, if it's a one-off, and cost doesn't matter.